# CreateNavigator (X-Path has invalid token)

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I am trying to enumerate all the namespaces in a document using XPath.
The following works in xmlspy, but not in .NET

```
//*/namespace-uri(.)

// Executing this in linqpad, I get the error below.
xml.CreateNavigator().Select("//*/namespace-uri(.)").Dump();
// the error below.
XPathException: ('//*/namespace-uri(.)' has an invalid token)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else trying this here is the code that works.

```
(element.XPathEvaluate("//namespace::*") as IEnumerable).OfType<XAttribute>().Distinct()
```

Regards

Me